# "He may often be seen in the Temple" -- how do I interpret "may often"?

Tags: modal-verbs, adverbs

Here is a sentence from a video game:

> All know the emperor to be a good and holy man, for he **may often be seen** in the Temple of the One, making his devotions to the Nine Divines and the Communion of Saints.

I would understand it if it used *can often*, but *may often* doesn't currently make much sense to me.

I know that *may* can signify either permission or possibility, and I guess here it means the latter. *Can* would mean that the emperor visits the temple often, and *may*, as far as I understand, adds the author's uncertainty, or ignorance, to the meaning of *can* (the author doesn't know exactly whether the emperor visits the temple often, but thinks he definitely does once in a while).

---

Having written all that, I would like to ask: does *may often* mean that the author thinks the emperor definitely visits the temple, but doesn't know how often he does so?

Also, couldn't this *may* (compared to *can*) imply some disrespect for the emperor in terms of his godliness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can* would mean that the emperor visits the temple often, and *may*, as far as I understand, adds the author's uncertainty, or ignorance, to the meaning of *can* (the author doesn't know exactly **whether the emperor visits** the temple often, but thinks he definitely does once in a while).

My guess is that **may** affects not the fact of the emperor's visits to the temple. He does visit the Temple often, being a good and holy man.

**May** affects your typical Joe's chances of seeing the emperor. He might see the emperor during a service, but on the other hand he might not. Speaking generally, the emperor may often be seen by the public there.

> It is often possible to observe the emperor in the Temple, making devotions.

Yes, the modal **can** could be used in the place of **may**, and it would even be more natural in modern English.

The use of **may** is your quote is a bit formal. Let me quote from Quirk et al. ([A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Comprehensive_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), Unit 4.53, 'May/Might'):

> Less commonly, in formal English, *may/might* is used in the same possibility sense as *can/could*, a sense which may be distinguished by the label ROOT POSSIBILITY:
>
> 'During the autunm, many rare birds *may* be observed on the rocky northern coasts of the island.' [4]
>
> *May* in [4] is a more formal substitute for *can*, and the whole sentence could be paraphrased *It is possible to observe...*

---

Here's an interesting Ngram:

[image]

It can be seen how 'can often be seen' has been overtaking 'may often be seen'.